# CI/CD Junit tests: should I build the package first or I can run the test firsts?

Tags: java, testing, continuous-integration

Regarding a pipeline of CI/CD when you want to run all the junit tests from the pipeline you should build first the code and then run the tests or you can first run the tests and if they pass run the build ?

Steps:

- Code
- Push
- Test ?
- Build ?
- Deploy

Is this the order ?

Consider a classic environment with Maven where you run `mvnw test` to run the tests.

I am asking this because for example [in this video](https://youtu.be/muQmkzNL7B0?t=257), there is first the build step and then the test step

Comment: running the tests should be part of the building process. What is the point of having a built release if the tests fail?

Comment: That's right. I am asking this because for example in this video: https://youtu.be/muQmkzNL7B0?t=257 there is first the step of build and then the tests.. So I didn't understand

Comment: consider running `mvn clean install` which will trigger both build and running tests

Comment: @HưngChu: ok thanks, but the questions is why build first and then after test? Should one test before and if tests pass then build ? Maybe you need to build to run tests ?

Answer (score 2):

I answer myself: to run tests for compiled languages (Java, C++, etc) you need to build first.

For interpreted languages that doens't need compilation you can simply run tests